# Call a js with GET parameters

Tags: javascript, get

I need someone to enlighten me.
I've seen this:

```
<script src="http://host.com/file.js?no_forms=1"></script>
```

What does that means? A GET parameter passed to a javascript file?
Into which conditions this can be done?
What kind of approach is this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every time you make a request to the server, the latest version of the js file will be downloaded to the client side. When ever you make any change in js file, you don't have to clear your browser cache to affect the js changes, it will get the latest version file automatically from the server if you specify parameter after the url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "?" sign mean in a request for a static JS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615199/what-does-the-sign-mean-in-a-request-for-a-static-js-file)

Comment: @FelixKling If there's no other reason why a GET parameter is passed when getting a .js file, yes, I think it's a duplicate. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?no_forms=1` is just a query string parameters. i will just tell the common usage of such things.

- Used for to avoid caching (get new updated version of JS)
- Some sort of redirection
- Even some application usage ideas.

Comment: Well, in fact that seems to be the usage - avoid `caching`; because I'm on a development environment and file.js is being changed a lot by other team.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the parameter is used simply to prevent client side caching.

It could also be that requesting `file.js` is actually rewritten as a dynamic call (say `script.php?file=file.js&no_forms=1`) that is fetching the correct file and using the extra parameter somehow.

Comment: Like I said to @Ravi that seems to be the usage - avoid `caching`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
<script src="http://host.com/file.js" no_forms="1"></script>
```

**And**

```
function $_GET(q,s) {
    s = s || window.location.search;
    var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'=([^&]*)','i');
    return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&').match(re)) ? s=s[1] : s='';
}
```

**And get result**

```
var noForms = $_GET('no_forms');
```

Comment: this will invalidate the HTML structure, as the attribute is not in the HTML standards.

Comment: NP, use "data-no-forms"